# How to pass dataset id to bigquery client for python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I just started playing around with bigquery, and I am trying to pass the dataset id to the python client. It should be a pretty basic operation, but I can't find it on other threads.

In practice I would like to to take the following example

```
# import packages
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery

# set current work directory to the one with this script.
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# initialize client object using the bigquery key I generated from Google clouds
google_credentials_path = 'bigquery-stackoverflow-DC-fdb49371cf87.json'
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(google_credentials_path)

# create simple query
query_job = client.query(
    """
    SELECT
      CONCAT(
        'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',
        CAST(id as STRING)) as url,
      view_count
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
    WHERE tags like '%google-bigquery%'
    ORDER BY view_count DESC
    LIMIT 10"""
)

# store results in dataframe
dataframe_query = query_job.result().to_dataframe()
```

and make it look something like

```
# import packages
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery

# set current work directory to the one with this script.
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# initialize client object using the bigquery key I generated from Google clouds
google_credentials_path = 'bigquery-stackoverflow-DC-fdb49371cf87.json'
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(google_credentials_path)\
                        .A_function_to_specify_id(bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow)

# create simple query
query_job = client.query(
    """
    SELECT
      CONCAT(
        'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',
        CAST(id as STRING)) as url,
      view_count
    FROM `posts_questions` -- No dataset ID here anymore
    WHERE tags like 'google-bigquery'
    ORDER BY view_count DESC
    LIMIT 10"""
)

# store results in dataframe
dataframe_query = query_job.result().to_dataframe()
```

The documentation eludes me, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to what you're asking for is the `default_dataset` ([reference](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.default_dataset)) property of the query job config.  The query job config is an optional object that can be passed into the `query()` method of the instantiated BigQuery client.

You don't set default dataset as part of instantiating a client as not all resources are dataset scoped. You're implicitly working with a query job in your example, which is a project scoped resource.

So, to adapt your sample a bit, it might look something like this:

```
# skip the irrelevant bits like imports and client construction

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(default_dataset="bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow")

sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM posts_questions WHERE tags like 'google-bigquery'"

dataframe = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()
```

If you're issuing multiple queries against this same dataset you could certainly reuse the same job config object with multiple query invocations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is exactly what I was looking for!